# Facebook Graph API: With an App access token, can I obtain users with a certain name?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

My goal is to search all users matching a specified name without the need for the user to be logged in with facebook. To accomplish this I did the following:

- I created a Facebook App.
- By using PHP I obtained the App access
  token.

The problem is when I execute the api call: 
`"search?q=$name&type=user&access_token=$app_access_token";`

I get the following result: "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint"

The question is, **can I search users matching a specified name with my App Access Token or do I need a User Access Token?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a user access token (can be you as a user).

Comment: What do you mean by: "can be you as a user". Please remember I don't want the user to log in with facebook, I want to accomplish this transparently for the user.

Comment: Yepp. Just YOU log in and take YOUR USER ACCESS TOKEN and do a querey search.

Comment: So should I create a dummy user to be used for this app that i'm developping. And transparently for the user log in with the dummy user?

Comment: As and idea. This user is actually not disclosed since you can currently not see who has searched for your name or id or visited your timeline

Comment: My doubt is, should I develop sort of an auto-login for my dummy user (without me entering my login credentials), to then get the access token and execute the graph api call?